# Cassandra sstableloader, no data restored

Tags: docker, cassandra, nosql

i've been trying to use sstableloader to restore a snapshot, and while i don't have any exception when doing so, no data is restored on my new node.

here is the result of `sstableloader -d newNodeIp keyspaceFolder`:

> Established connection to initial hosts
>   Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
>   
>   Summary statistics:
>       Connections per host    : 1
>       Total files transferred : 0
>       Total bytes transferred : 0.000KiB
>       Total duration          : 2637 ms
>       Average transfer rate   : 0.000KiB/s
>       Peak transfer rate      : 0.000KiB/s

i've tried running it either from the node the backup comes from or from another remote host, the result is the same.
the cassandra version is the latest stable one as of this post (3.11.1).
the source and destination keyspaces have the same name.

the folder containing the backup is structured as such:

> keyspaceName/table-uuid/

^ each of these folders containing sstable files.
none of these folders contain subfolders (no backups / snapshots subfolders).
the corresponding folders on the new node are similarly named (with the exception of the uuid obviously).
should that be of interest, each node is a docker container.

any clue as to why sstableloader wouldn't be able to restore my backup please?
am i using it wrong?
don't hesitate to point out any missing info.

Comment: In what folder did you run sstableloader?

Comment: @Horia if from the previous node directly, from the data folder (so the keyspaceFolder was the one that was used on that node).    
if from the remote host, the folder i extracted my backup to, the backup being structured as it was on the node.

Comment: add also table name, not only the keyspace

Comment: @Horia thank you, it was indeed in the doc, my mistake...  i now have an issue with the stream (stream failed when trying to connect to newNodeIp:7000, while i can telnet just fine to the ip and port), any idea please?

Comment: I think you should provide more info on this one and open a new question. First thing that I would try is to change between names and ip's to check if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add also table name, not only the keyspace.